# WCF Authentication Service Slow

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-authentication

Im using the built in Authentication Service to check if a user is valid.

Testing in SOAP UI, each request i make takes longer each time.

I catch this event, AuthenticationService_Authenticating in global.asax, to check some other criteria on the login..  would this have anything to do it?

Thanks
Neil

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the event was being raised in global.asax  Session_Start instead of the Application_Start() :)

So the event was getting raised on each new session meaning a single login would raise 100s of events after a while for the Autheticating method.